# How to find HTML control in ItemDataBound without runat="server" attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the anchor tag

```
<a id="lnkhide" onclick='Click_Anchor(<%#Convert.ToString(Eval("EmployeeLeaveID")) %>)'  clientidmode="Static">Click</a>
```

Here is javascript Function when click on anchor tag Click_Anchor() method call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Click_Anchor(0)
        });
        function Click_Anchor(id)
        {
            var element = '#' + id;
            $('.RejectionReason').css("display", "none");
            $(element).css({"display": "block"});

        }

    </script>
```

here is ItemDataBound Method

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
HtmlAnchor lnkAnchorRejection = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("lnkhide"); 
}
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that.  As far as the server is concerned a control with out the  `runat="server"` attribute is just HTML text.   There is no corresponding object to work on.  Why don't you use an asp.net HtmlAnchor or HyperLink control?

Comment: Thanks Steve Wellens. when i put runat="server" attribute then onclick='Click_Anchor(<%#Convert.ToString(Eval("EmployeeLeaveID")) %>)' cant call properly.

Comment: Use `OnClientClick` instead of `onclick` when used with `runat="sever"`.

Comment: I get the following HTML when page render
<a id="lnkAnchorReject" onclientclick="Click_Anchor(<%# Convert.ToString(Eval(&quot;EmployeeLeaveID&quot;)) %>)"></a>

Comment: Use `<asp:HyperLink>`

Comment: Mairaj Ahmad same result while using <asp:HyperLink>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time research i fount that a control with out the `runat="server"` attribute is just an html element and you can not access at server side.